# Getting the error "root module does not declare a variable of that name." from Terraform even though I am specifying the command as an argument?

Tags: terraform

Here is my dir structure:

```
├── main.tf
├── modules
│   ├── subnets
│   │   ├── main.tf
│   │   ├── outputs.tf
│   │   └── variables.tf
│   ├── variables.tf
│   └── vpc
│       ├── main.tf
│       ├── outputs.tf
│       └── variables.tf
├── outputs.tf
└── variables.tf
```

and my `modules/vpc/main.tf`

```
resource "aws_vpc" "env_vpc" {
  cidr_block           = "${var.vpc_cidr_block}"
  enable_dns_support   = "${var.vpc_enable_dns_support}"
  enable_dns_hostnames = "${var.vpc_enable_dns_hostnames}"

  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.env_name}-vpc"
    Provisioner = "Terraform"
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

and my `modules/vpc/variables.tf`

```
variable "env_name" {
    description = "The name of the env the VPC will belong to"
    # no default provided
}
```

When I perform `terraform plan`

```
➢  terraform plan

Error: Missing required argument

  on main.tf line 1, in module "vpc":
   1: module "vpc" {

The argument "env_name" is required, but no definition was found.
```

When I pass the var in the cmd:

```
➢  terraform plan -var 'env_name=ffff'

Error: Value for undeclared variable

A variable named "env_name" was assigned on the command line, but the root
module does not declare a variable of that name. To use this value, add a
"variable" block to the configuration.
```

The problem does not go away even when I declare the variable in root `variables.tf`

as in

```
➢  cat variables.tf
variable "env_name" {}
```

any suggestions?

**edit**: When I provided a `default` value for that variable, the `plan` worked. It **did** ask me interactively for an `env_name` value but the `plan` output was with the `default` value. Why is that?

**edit2**: Clarification about the contents of the `variables.tf` files:

- On the **root** directory:

```
➢  ls
main.tf      modules      outputs.tf   variables.tf
➢  cat variables.tf
variable "env_name" {}
```

In the `modules/vpc` directory:

```
➢  ls
main.tf      outputs.tf   variables.tf
aws_vpc/modules/vpc  stand_alone_vpc ✗   

➢  cat variables.tf
variable "env_name" {
    description = "The name of the environment/microservice the VPC will belong to"
    default = "wbl"
}
```

It **asks** me to input the `env_name` value, but it **ignores** it and makes use of the `default`, as set in `modules/vpc/variables.tf`. Here is the `plan`:

```
➢  terraform plan
var.env_name
  Enter a value: foo

Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.


------------------------------------------------------------------------

An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.vpc.aws_internet_gateway.env_igw will be created
  + resource "aws_internet_gateway" "env_igw" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + owner_id = (known after apply)
      + tags     = {
          + "Name"        = "wbl-igw"
          + "Provisioner" = "Terraform"
        }
      + vpc_id   = (known after apply)
    }

  # module.vpc.aws_vpc.env_vpc will be created
  + resource "aws_vpc" "env_vpc" {
      + arn                              = (known after apply)
      + assign_generated_ipv6_cidr_block = false
      + cidr_block                       = "10.0.0.0/16"
      + default_network_acl_id           = (known after apply)
      + default_route_table_id           = (known after apply)
      + default_security_group_id        = (known after apply)
      + dhcp_options_id                  = (known after apply)
      + enable_classiclink               = (known after apply)
      + enable_classiclink_dns_support   = (known after apply)
      + enable_dns_hostnames             = true
      + enable_dns_support               = true
      + id                               = (known after apply)
      + instance_tenancy                 = "default"
      + ipv6_association_id              = (known after apply)
      + ipv6_cidr_block                  = (known after apply)
      + main_route_table_id              = (known after apply)
      + owner_id                         = (known after apply)
      + tags                             = {
          + "Name"        = "wbl-vpc"
          + "Provisioner" = "Terraform"
        }
    }

Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

------------------------------------------------------------------------

Note: You didn't specify an "-out" parameter to save this plan, so Terraform
can't guarantee that exactly these actions will be performed if
"terraform apply" is subsequently run.
```

Comment: I have added it in root `variables.tf` as in `variable "env_name" {}`

Comment: The problem now (as I suggest in my edit) is that __although__ interactively it asks me for the `env_name` variable, and I provide it, it runs the plan with the default value of `env_name` as found in `modules/vpc/variables.tf` (and I cannot override it)

Comment: pkaramol, can you please clarify which `variables.tf` you're printing at the end? Also, can you addthe contents of the top-level `variables.tf` file (the one at the very bottom of your directory tree)?

Comment: @supersam654 pls check my second edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the way around this (i.e. to be able to override the `default` value set in the submodule's `variable.tf`) is the following:

**1**) declare the variable in the top (root) level `variables.tf`, as in

```
> $ cat variables.tf
variable "env_name" {
  default = "top-level"
}
```

**2**) set the variable value in the section of root's module `main.tf` that calls the submodule, as in:

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "./modules/vpc"
  # variables
  env_name = "${var.env_name}"
}
```

This way, the variable that will end up being passed to the submodule, is the one declared in the parent module's `variables.tf`